# Why does the findPaths function decrements the i and j variables after displaying the vector?

Tags: c++

1. This program finds all possible paths from top left to bottom right of a matrix.
2. 'isvalid' checks if (i, j) is valid matrix coordinate
3. 'printPath' prints the route taken
4. 'findPaths' saves the content on a vector and checks if the path can go right or down

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
#define M 3
#define N 3
 
// Function to check if (i, j) is valid matrix coordinate

bool isvalid(int i, int j)
{
    return (i >= 0 && i < M && j >= 0 && j < N);
}
 
// Function to print the route taken

void printPath(vector<int> const &path, int last)
{
    for (int i : path)
        cout << i << " - ";
    cout << last << endl;
}
 

void findPaths(int mat[][N], vector<int> &path, int i, int j)
{
    // if we have reached the last cell, print the route
    if (i == M - 1 && j == N - 1)
    {
        printPath(path, mat[i][j]);
        return;
    }
 
    // include current cell in path
    path.push_back(mat[i][j]);
 
    // move right
    if (isvalid(i, j + 1))
        findPaths(mat, path, i, j + 1);
 
    // move down
    if (isvalid(i + 1, j))
        findPaths(mat, path, i + 1, j);
 
    // remove current cell from the path
    path.pop_back();
}
 
int main()
{
    int mat[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };
 
    vector<int> path;
 
    // start from (0, 0) cell
    int x = 0, y = 0;
 
    findPaths(mat, path, x, y);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. Why do you think it does? What input do you put in, what do you debug or print out, and what exact output do you see that makes you think they are decremented?

Comment: The posted `findPaths` function doesn't seem decrementing `i` and `j`.

Comment: when I debug after the return inside the findPaths() function the variables decrement, I use Xcode

Comment: It does not decrement - you're unwinding the recursion stepping back to another stack frame and seeing local parameters `i` and `j` from that previous stack frame where they have those values (lower by 1 than in the higher stack frame). You must learn a bit how the debugger works and what it shows you.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how the function works then? Sorry but I'm new to c++.

Comment: It is not C++ specific, just a generality of programming languages that support functions. You want to search or check your book's index for _recursion_.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will search about recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in Recursion we are making calls with i + 1 and j + 1;
So when we make a call to the function in recursive way think of it as a new function that does same thing but with i + 1 and j + 1 value. So it will keep on making new function it the last function it make reaches its end } or it encounters a return statement. Then last function will be destroyed and we will be at second last function (which has i - 1 and j - 1 value and this will be our new last function). this may not be very accurate but i think it is a good way to understand.

Think of recursion like you are standing in a line and you want to know at what position you are standing but line is too long to be able to look and tell, So you ask a guy standing in front of you and he also doesn't know so he ask the guy in front of him and so on and on till we reach a guy who knows on which position he is standing so he say something like i am standing on 4th position to guy behind him(Now we start going back). guy behind him add one to it and say I am on 5th position and so on and on till it reaches back to us.